# jQueryUI At the time of drop, create a different element

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am trying to do something similar to this example I found here: http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/sY7Vr/2/

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
items: ".drag",
connectWith: ".sortable",
start: function( event, ui ) {
    $(ui.item).text("Drop me!");
},
stop: function(event, ui) {
    $(ui.item).text("Drag me!");
},
receive: function( event, ui ) {
    $(ui.item)
        .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
        .after(
            $("<div>")
                .addClass("drag")
                .html("New item!")
        );
}
});
```

In my case, I have an action bar that contains 'buttons' and a page. When I drag an action 'button' from the action bar (ie "Add text box") and do the drop, I want to insert a input rather than the button itself.

Is there a good way to do this?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is replace the content in the `html` method. The code below is inserting the `html` for an `input` of type `text` and is then removing the dragged item.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/sY7Vr/245/)

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
  items: ".drag",
  connectWith: ".sortable",
  start: function( event, ui ) {
    $(ui.item).text("Drop me!");
  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    $(ui.item).text("Drag me!");
  },
  receive: function( event, ui ) {
    $(ui.item)
      .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
      .after(
      $("<div>")
      .html("<input type='text' class='new-input'/>") //Add an input
    );
    //Remove the dragged item. You can use "hide" here as well
    $(ui.item).remove();
  }
});
```